# In CakePHP 2 how to insert input field without creating form?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, formhelper

I'd like to create well formatted Form element with Form helper but without creation of form itself. So i wrote:

```
$this->Form->input(
    'Kid.id', 
    array(
        'type' => 'text',
    )
);
```

This is ajax inside "Kids" controller response, and I'd like to update form after user make some actions.

I have no idea how to do it, except manually write HTML code.

Comment: So you want the page to create a form element that gets populated after some other actions on the page are completed? What do you need to do with this form afterwards (assuming some submit function)?

Comment: User fills some part of form and depending on what did he wrote rest of form is loaded. I know that I cane write explicitly pure HTML or divide form on two pages. But I'd like to know if cakePHP can produce form fields itself without creating a form.

Comment: That should work. Did you notice you missed out the 'echo' at the start of the line?

Comment: Note that dynamically updating forms on your page will not work together with the Security component, which provides form-tampering. You may not need Security now, but if you decide to use it later your setup will backfire. In this case I would recommend using Javascript+Ajax to auto-submit the form when the field you are interested in changes, **replacing** the form with a new one *in situ* (generated by the Form handler, of course).

Comment: You're right @RichardAtHome I forgot to wirte `echo`... Shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me. This works I just forgot to add an `echo` at the beginning of line.